# .htaccess and php get parameter (cyrillic alphabet) with $_GET["id"]

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After creating clean URL with .htaccess. I have a problem with my $_GET["id"] parameter in Cyrillic alphabet.
If I insert a parameter with Latin alphabet it work but not with Cyrillic. It works fine before.

Example:

```
#Latin
$id = $_GET["tea"];

echo $id; # Output is: tea

# Cyrillic
$id = $_GET["чай"];
echo $id; # Output is: ???
```

My HTML header is

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="ru">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 ...
```

I am sure something is wrong with .htaccess not php because if I get Cyrillic text from database it work fine. Only $_GET["id"] not work.

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^id=RU$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z-яА-Я0-9]+) product.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z-яА-Я0-9]+) products.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ссылки/([a-zA-Z-яА-Я0-9]+) backlinks.php [NC,L]

# .php 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: php- and htaccess-files should be saved in utf-8 w/o BOM

Comment: Your regex `a-zA-Z-яА-Я0-9` seems to be invalid, because of `-я` without a start of range.